# Publishing whole file as a single message in Kafka topic using Java

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a use case where I need to publish whole file as a single message using Kafka Producer, so that when the consumer reads the message, consumer should be able to able to get whole file.
I tried implementing this by converting the file to byte array and publish it to topic

```
byte[] fileData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, byte[]>("test", fileData));
```

When the same is consumed, each line is coming as a separate message

Comment: Did you resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka has a default record size of 1MB, and is **not** meant for file delivery.

The **recommended** pattern is to

1. Upload your file to a shared filesystem (such as S3)
2. Take the path to the file as a URI (such as `s3://path/to/file`)
3. Produce that URI in the topic record
4. Consume
5. Download file from filesystem

---

Without seeing your consumer, it's hard to diagnose your exact issue *with the consumer*, but you are reading the file fine.